# Parse XML document securely

Tags: java

How do I parse an XML document securely so that it does not allow external entities as part of an incoming XML document? I am using DOM parser -

```
Document test = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream))
```

Comment: You would like to read this [BlackHat paper](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Wang-FileCry-The-New-Age-Of-XXE-java-wp.pdf) on how your defences may not be providing security with respect to XXE attacks. It also mentions what @erickson pointed about FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can request secure processing by setting [`FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING`;](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING) whether this prohibits external entities is up to the provider of the `DocumentBuilderFactory`, but it's a likely candidate.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
f.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
Document test = f.newDocumentBuilder.parse(...);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that you should also set 
`f.setFeature( "http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false );`
Otherwise you are still vulnerable to external entity attacks:

`org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
calls
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
calls
sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
f.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false); 
f.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false); 
f.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false); 
f.setXIncludeAware(false); 
f.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

Document test = f.newDocumentBuilder.parse(...);
```

To avoid external entity expansion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).